# Magento 1.9 - OroCRM consuming my resource 100%. How to manage proper way?

Tags: resources, magento-1.9, cpu-usage, orocrm

I am using OroCRM version 3, my cpu resource reached 100%, how to manage proper way? Anything necessary steps i should be follow while connection OroCRM?

Comment: It could be first time when you load the data, because consumers get all your resources to process the messages. Once all messages (tasks) will be done there is nothing todo for consumers, so your resources will be get back to you.

Comment: You can check what exact processes take your resources, and in case of consumers you can check the queue and number of tasks in it.

Comment: @SerhiiPolishchuk Could you pls help me how can i find  what exact processes take your resources?

Comment: I'm using `htop` utility. There is possibility to sort processes by CPU or memory

Comment: @SerhiiPolishchuk How to use htop?

Comment: did you use Linux? You should search about how to use htop on Linux somewhere in internet, e.g. https://www.deonsworld.co.za/2012/12/20/understanding-and-using-htop-monitor-system-resources/
In case you use Windows you should see other native process manager